# scala read the configs dynamically during run time

Tags: scala, maven, config

I have a config file in the below folder subtract

```
main
    scala
    resources
             application.conf
```

and that contains

```
path{
  http{
      url = "http://testingurl"

  }
}
```

I am reading using below code

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

val url = conf.getString("path.http.url")
```

I am reading this static information which is provided durng build time.

Now I want to read these in runtime, user should be able to modify configs even after jar is built.

my requirement is to modify url event after jar is build, I dont want to pass as a arguments to the main function because I have so many such values which needs to modified after jar built

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:
[Lightbend Config Readme](https://github.com/lightbend/config)

Use at runtime:
`-Dconfig.file=<relative or absolute path>`

See:

```
For applications using application.{conf,json,properties}, 
system properties can be used to force a different config source 
    (e.g. from command line -Dconfig.file=path/to/config-file):

    config.resource specifies a resource name - not a basename, i.e. application.conf not application
    config.file specifies a filesystem path, again it should include the extension, not be a basename
    config.url specifies a URL

These system properties specify a replacement for application.{conf,json,properties}, not an addition. 
They only affect apps using the default ConfigFactory.load() configuration. 
In the replacement config file, you can use include "application" to include the original default config file; 
after the include statement you could go on to override certain settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a .jar file is build with a key provided as

> val url = conf.getString("path.http.url")

and you are going to run this .jar every time with modified `.config` file

> my requirement is to modify url event after jar is build,

a possible solution is to provide a array of the config values, where key remains same in .jar file

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

ConfigFactory.load().getStringList("url.key").stream().map(eachUrl => functionToBeCalled)
```